# Installing KVM on Oracle Solaris

Tags: kvm-virtualization, solaris, qemu, hypervisor, emulator

As searched shown KVM is not bare-metal and can be installed on some Linux distros, I wonder is it possible to install KVM hypervisor on Solaris?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no, it depends on what you actually want from it. Do you want the /dev/kvm API or do you just want to run hardware-accelerated `qemu`?

The core KVM hypervisor isn't a regular program; it is an integral part of the Linux kernel. It's not something you install from your distro, and it's not something you can simply compile and run on a non-Linux system.

But KVM does nothing on its own – it is usually managed through Qemu where it acts as an "accelerator" backend – that is, KVM supervises the virtual CPUs but Qemu emulates all the remaining hardware (disks, GPUs, network interfaces). When most people talk about running VMs via KVM, they usually mean `qemu -accel kvm` (or sometimes alternatives like `kvmtool`).

Qemu *can* run on other operating systems, as long as they have *a* supported hypervisor – it doesn't need Linux KVM specifically. In theory you should get the same results with e.g. `qemu -accel haxm` on Windows as with Linux KVM.

That said, KVM *has* apparently been [ported](https://github.com/joyent/illumos-kvm) to **Illumos**, which is a Solaris derivative, and is used in the [SmartOS](https://www.joyent.com/smartos) product. (Of course, while illumos-kvm is *based on* Linux KVM, they are no longer the same as both have diverged in their own ways since then – they both just provide the same /dev/kvm API to userspace programs.)

So if you want to run `qemu -enable-kvm` on Illumos/OmniOS/SmartOS, you can do that. There is no KVM on OpenSolaris, however – at least not that I could find.

Comment: I don't know what _is_ available on Solaris... There's Oracle VirtualBox, I guess? (Bare qemu without a supported hypervisor backend would be slow, as it'd have to use CPU-based emulation.)

Comment: Oracle VirtualBox is a emulator but i am looking for hypervisor!

Comment: No, they work the same way though... Both qemu-kvm _and_ virtualbox use a hosted hypervisor with hardware acceleration (qemu uses KVM, virtualbox uses its own kernel driver) whenever possible, and both emulate what isn't possible to virtualize.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris for Sparc and Intel are capable to run the Oracle (Zen) based Hyper-visor environment. They provide full featured virtualisation environments.

The IOS can be downloaded from this link: https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/server-storage-vm-downloads.html

Some require a Oracle account (that does not need to be associated with a support contract). Though some features require an enterprise support contract. Personal use is O.K. providing it is not on behalf of company or organisation.